# Creating a hole by removing a set

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

We informally say that a space has a hole if it’s identity map is not nullhomotopic, and classify different kinds of holes in a space with homotopy groups. However, I was wondering if there is some to say that a hole is created by removing some subset from a space (taking the subspace topology on its relative complement). I think it can’t be reduced to the properties of the original space and the space with the set removed in isolation (I’m picturing puncturing a hole in an “infinite-holed solid torus” to obtain a set homeomorphic to the original), so a definition must directly or indirectly refer to the inclusion mapping between them. My intuition is that a hole is an obstruction that prevents some topological structure in a space from being moved somewhere else, so my current idea for a definition is this:

In a topological space $X$, the removal of $Y\subseteq X$ creates a hole if and only if, there exist $f,g$ with codomain $X$ and ranges that are subsets of $X\setminus Y$, such that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic in $X$ but are not homotopic in $X\setminus Y$ equipped with the subspace topology from $X$.

Comment: You might be interested in the topic of [knot theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory), with which one analyzes the consequences of removing a closed curve from three-dimensional space.

Comment: About "puncturing an infinite-holed torus": I don't believe that you can remove a non-empty set from an infinite-holed torus so that what remains still is an infinite-holed torus (or any non-empty two-manifold without boundary for that matter). Your picture works for the plane with infinitely many disks removed, though. But I wouldn't agree that this "doesn't create a hole".

Comment: @rawbacon I was referring to an infinite-holed solid torus, not its 2-manifold boundary. Basically picturing a chain with the links welded together and a hole drilled through one. I am unaware if there is actually a space called the “infinite-holed torus”, so I may be picturing something entirely different. I would agree in either case that this does create a hole, it certainly does by my definition.

Comment: Oh, my bad for not properly reading what I was criticising. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Your introductory sentence does not make much sense on its own: I cannot make much sense out of your informal definition "a space has a hole if it is not nullhomotopic" because I don't know what it means for a space to be nullhomotopic; that is not a standard terminology.

Comment: Also, your closing paragraph implies that removal of $(0,0)$ from $\mathbb R^2$ does **not** create a hole, because there exist $f,g : S^1 \to \mathbb R^2 - \{(0,0)\}$ such that $f,g$ are homotopic in $\mathbb R^2$ but are not homotopic in $\mathbb R^2 - \{(0,0)\}$. I suspect you are missing the word "not" somewhere in that paragraph.

Comment: Beyond these issues, do you have an actual question?

Comment: @Lee Mosher. Fixed. I was wondering if there was an actual widely accepted definition corresponding to this idea. I am not confident that mine is sufficient, although I’m happy that it’s necessary. I take it that there isn’t a widely accepted definition.

Comment: If I had to invent a definition to capture this notion, perhaps it would be that removal of $Y \subset X$ creates a hole if and only if the inclusion map $X-Y \hookrightarrow X$ is not a homotopy equivalence. I know of one isolated place where a related concept comes up, namely Bestvina's definition of a Z-set (to say that $Y \subset X$ is a Z-set means that several conditions hold, one of which is that the inclusion $Y-Z \hookrightarrow Y$ *is* a homotopy equivalence).

Comment: But there is not, as far as I know, any need for such a definition. The general process that drives the formulation of definitions is the need for a simple, evocative terminology to express an important but hard-to-express concept that arises over and over again in mathematical investigations. The need is enchanced by the desire to give shorter, more intuitive statements of theorems, without any loss of rigor.